# Rails cannot fetch application-xxxxxx.js webpack bundle - 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I recently updated webpacker, babel, and many other packages on my Rails project so that node-sass would work on the heroku-20 stack, and after enough fiddling webpacker is able to compile and start but when attempting to load any of the pages, Rails attempts to fetch `/packs/js/application-44959decf6e2f6f8700f.js` when Webpacker shows me it is bundled at `/packs/application-17d61f0126c1ef6152fd.js`. None of my React JS loads, only the Rails-rendered part shows.

My project is Ruby on Rails 5.2.8 (Ruby 2.7) with @rails/webpacker updated to 5.3.0, Webpack updated to 5.1.0, Node updated to 14.18.1. React version is 16.4.1.

Things I have tried:

- npx webpack init
- bundle exec rails webpacker:install
- copying config files from another app with the same Node/webpack versions and resetting them after getting the same errors

Completely stuck on this, any help is appreciated.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxx",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.5",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.6",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.8.1",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.snakecase": "^4.1.1",
    "nanoid": "^2.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.56",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-animate-height": "^2.0.7",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-geosuggest": "^2.9.0",
    "react-inlinesvg": "^1.1.7",
    "react-select": "^2.4.2",
    "react-tagsinput": "^3.19.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.8",
    "webpack": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpacker-react": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "eslint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.jsx ./app/javascript"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.x"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == "production";

const config = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3035
  },
};

module.exports = () => {
  if (isProduction) {
    config.mode = "production";
  } else {
    config.mode = "development";
  }
  return config;
};
```

config/webpacker.yml

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "transform-class-properties",
      {
        "spec": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '~> 2.7.6'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.8'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.2.3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'letter_opener', '>= 1.8.1'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'searchkick', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'parallel'
gem 'oj'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'webpacker-react', '~> 0.3.2'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'paranoia', '~> 2.2'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'select2-rails'
# gem 'select2-rails-latest' # update select2 to make dropdowns case-insensitive
gem 'attribute_normalizer'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'bunny'
gem 'kt-paperclip', '~> 6.4.2'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'lograge'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'restforce'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem "mimemagic", path: 'vendor/gems/mimemagic-0.3.2'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'pry'
gem 'elasticsearch'

group :test do
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'climate_control'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.14'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.29', require: false
  gem 'figaro'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Procfile.dev

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3002
webpack: yarn run webpack serve --mode=development
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
es: bin/elasticsearch-8.2.3/bin/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching to `bin/webpack-dev-server` instead of `yarn run webpack serve` in Procfile.dev. I then had to copy some intricate configuration files in config/webpack/ from another project with the same setup, then configure all of the loaders.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please, can you share with me the configurations files into your `config/webpack`

Comment: what configs did you paste?